# Excel Data Bar pointing to cell value

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm creating a spreadsheet for task completion and using the "data bar" function in excel. The Data bar is set for 1-100, with only the bar showing (no numbers). I would like the next cell over to reflect the status of the bar-like so:

> BLANK CELL - "Not Started"
>
> 1-99 (shown on data bar) - "In Progress"
>
> 100 (shown on data bar) - "Completed"

to make this happen, I tried

```
= IF(D3=" ","NOT STARTED", IF(AND(D3>=1,D3<=100),"IN PROGRESS",IF(D3=100,"COMPLETED")))
```

but all I get for any numeric value is "IN PROGRESS" and if the cell is blank, "FALSE"

I'm new to coding so any help appreciated. What am I doing wrong, or what code might work better?

Answer (score 0):

remove the space from the D3=" "

And you do not need the third IF.

Also since you put D3<=100 `IN PROGRESS` will fire even if D3 is 100

```
=IF(D3="","NOT STARTED", IF(AND(D3>=1,D3<100),"IN PROGRESS","COMPLETED"))
```

Comment: @DanielNelson-Mitchell please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.